# Android: pass a value from container Activity to its fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

My code contains a main Activity and three fragments inside it and I want to pass a value from the container activity to its fragment, but it's not working.
I tried to make an interface to communicate to each other but nothing happened.
I also tried to make a bundle but I have an error in `setArguments`.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in the fragment

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if(bundle != null){
    int i = bundle.getInt(key, defaulValue);
}
```

Can you please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show what kind of error are you getting by using fragments? Are you passing arguments once the fragment is added? Or are you passing them on fragment creation?

Comment: im passing the value from the container activity to the fragment . but its not working i am a beginner on android .

Comment: can u tell me how can i do it ?

Comment: well, you're not providing enough info to understand what is the problem actually. without knowing what is the problem, I can't give any answer. But maybe [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) will explain how to pass data from activity to arguments.

Comment: i dont have error but i am not receiving the value in the fragment .

Comment: Without knowing more about your problem. But I could suggest, that you could subclass Fragment and write a custom constructor, which retains the data you want to pass.

Comment: my application has the container activity that connects with obd2 and the fragments contains the counters so i have to pass the values (speed,RPM) to the counters

Comment: where in the fragment you are getting the arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with an Intent in your activity :

```
Intent a = new Intent (this, yourfragment.class);
a.putInt(key, value);
setIntent(a);
```

And in your fragment :

```
ActivityName activity = (ActivityName) getActivity();
Intent b= activity.getIntent();    
int Uid = b.getIntExtra(key);
```